# Android - How to handle touch event for unlinked text in linkified textView?

Tags: android, linkify

Say I have a Linear layout with a clickListener .
This linear Layout contains a textView with a linkifyHandler for hashtag starting with #.

If the text is "AAAAABBBBB",
then there are no links so pressing this text will perform clickListener of the Linear layout.

If the text us "AAA #BBBBB",
pressing #BBBBB will perform a clickListener defined in the linkfyHandler.
However, pressing AAA doesn't do anything.

Is there a way to make it perform the clickListener of the linear layout when pressing AAA, the unlinked portion of the textview?

Thanks